# Developer Capacity Planning

Tags: project-management, capacity-planning

What product or tool do you use to do Resource Capacity planning for your development team? Currently managing a large group and trying to provide visibility into my resource availability. I am creating this in MS project, but was curious if there was a better tool/solution based off your experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the "Evidence-Based Scheduling" features in [FogBugz 7](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/learnmore.html#hist_DeveloperShipDates).

Answer (score 1):

We use a Scrum backlog.

It's a list of sprints -- in priority order -- people assigned to sprints and tentative schedule.

Since the users prioritize the sprints, it's very, very visible.

There's no need for MS-project; that's overkill.  A simple list based on cards tacked to a bulletin board is sufficient.   A spreadsheet will work, also.